# The TI quad-XOR gate acts as it is short circuit

Tags: digital-logic, testing

I have a TEXAS INSTRUMENTS CD4030BE Quad Exclusive-OR gate. I have an electronic board of

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2facPqW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

using [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink) and [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button) refrence. According to the XOR [data-sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4030b-mil.pdf):

I should have `A ⊕ B = J`. However, what I get is that when I press any of the pushbuttons all three LEDs are on:

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show any power connection to the IC

Comment: Your breadboard pictures don't either. Things generally work better when they're powered. Hook up your 5V supply to the VDD pin, and connect the VSS pin of the chip to ground.

Comment: @EugeneSh. there is none. It just works like that!

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat the breadboard works just like that. I suppose I need to connect VDD to the +5V and the the VSS to the GND, if the gate works properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is very simple - you have not connected the power supply to the IC.

In that state, *nothing* can be predicted with certainty about how it will operate - you are outside of its specifications. The ESD protection diodes can allow current from input pins to (incorrectly) partially power the IC, so the IC may not appear *dead*, but it may operate in unknown, unpredictable, ways - as you are seeing. So, don't do that! Correctly power the IC.

(FYI, you also have unconnected inputs, which can be a problem on CMOS ICs. Unconnected CMOS inputs can float to intermediate voltage levels (neither a valid logic high nor a valid logic low) and lead to high power consumption, potentially even causing internal damage to the IC. This has been covered in previous questions. You need to correctly pull-up or down any unused CMOS inputs.)

Comment: That's both embarrassing and wired at the same time. had some issues with the bigger board so I was trying to isolate the XOR to see if that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Foad - Hi, Provided you connect the power supply correctly (and connect all unused *inputs* to Gnd, for example, - leave unused *outputs* unconnected) then you can test the XOR gate shown in your schematic. Hopefully, it has not been damaged, but I have seen CMOS ICs damaged by (mistakenly) powering them only via input pins.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't connected the other inputs to GND yet, but it works properly now.

Comment: @Foad - I'm glad it now works properly with power connected. Please do connect the unused *inputs* to Gnd (or to Vdd (i.e. +5V in your case) if the wiring to do it is easier). Another reason for doing that, in addition to possible heating inside the IC due to the floating inputs, is unconnected CMOS inputs are static-sensitive and are prone to damage because of that. For some more background (albeit more in-depth than you might want right now), you can see [here](http://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/737694) and [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba004d/scba004d.pdf). I hope that's useful.